# Como resolver esses dois problemas no meu código?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**O que eu estou fazendo?**

Bom, eu estou criando um controle deslizante (`<input="range">`) no qual você passa o mouse por cima dele e ele mostra o seu valor em uma `<div>`e essa `<div>` tem o objetivo de seguir o controle deslizante conforme o usuário movimenta ele, mas essa `<div>` deve seguir de uma forma bem suave, esse controle deslizante é semelhante ao do desenvolvedor [@tadaima](https://codepen.io/tadaima/pen/XpyKPq). Já o meu controle deslizante está na minha conta do [CodePen](https://codepen.io/leandro-do-nascimento/pen/povJBdN).

A imagem abaixo é do controle deslizante com o seu respectivo valor dentro de uma `<div>`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O primeiro problema (movimento nada agradável)**

A primeira coisa de errado que está acontecendo no controle deslizante é quando você o movimenta e a `<div>` não acompanha ele de uma forma suave, ela vai travando as vezes, caso você movimente o controle deslizante bem devagar a `<div>` consegue acompanhá-lo mas o intuito é se movimentar rápido ou não ela siga acompanhá-lo do mesmo jeito de uma forma suave.

**O segundo problema (indo longe de mais)**

O segundo problema é que ao movimentar o controle deslizante rápido para direita / esquerda a `<div>` vai um pouco a mais do que deveria, pois o mínimo que ela deve ir é até no começo do controle deslizante e já o máximo que ela deveria ir é até no final do controle deslizante e não um pouco a mais.

A imagem abaixo mostra a `<div>` indo um pouco a mais do que deveria (isso acontece quando você movimenta rápido o controle deslizante para a esquerda / direita o máximo possível):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esses dois problemas a cima no meu código são os que "eu não consigo resolver", pois já tentei de várias formas e sem resultado quem poder ajudar, agradeço muito!

**NOTA:** Caso, tiver algum jeito de fazer melhor o que estou fazendo, seja com *JavaScript* puro ou *Jquery* ou com qual for a tecnologia toda ajuda é bem, vinda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o primeiro problema no css do `#ballon` pode reduzir o tempo ou remover a linha:

```
transition: left 250ms linear;
```

Para o segundo problema no `oninput` do button control:

1. Ficar com o ballon totalmente dentro da projeção da largura do button control, onde 250 é a largura do button control (300) menos e da largura do ballon (50):

`balloon.style.left = buttonControl.value * 250 / 100 + 'px';`

2. Ficar metade do ballon na projeção da largura do button control, onde 25 é metade da largura do ballon:

`balloon.style.left = buttonControl.value * 300 / 100 - 25 + 'px';`

3. Ficar centrado com a bola do button control, onde 270 é a largura do button control menos largura da bola e 10 é metade da largura da bola com a largura do ballon.

`balloon.style.left = buttonControl.value * 270 / 100 - 10 + 'px';`

Comment: Isso, mesmo!  valeu pela ajuda!